# Laplace operator and Fourier transform

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be a function with compact support in $D\subset \mathbf{R}^2$. Is is known that $$-\Delta f=F^{-1}|x|^2 F f,$$ where $F$ is the Fourier transform. Which is the $n-$dimensional analogous formula?

Comment: this holds in any dimension, doesn't it?

Comment: Essentially yes, but you have to worry about your class of functions and how Fourier transform is defined: multiplication by $|x|^2$ can bring you out of range of the Fourier transform.

Comment: When $f$ has compact support, its Fourier transform is in the Paley-Wiener space, and in particular is of rapid decay. Thus, multiplication by $|x|^2$ produces another function of rapid decay, certainly ok to apply Fourier transform... and the identity is correct, up to normalizing constant.

Comment: @paulgarrett: if $f$ has compact support, its Fourier Transform is analytic, but it does not need to decay rapidly. If $f$ is *smooth*, its Fourier transform decays rapidly at infinity.

Comment: @robjohn, oop! Yes, indeed! :)

Answer (score 4):

As long as $f$ does not have any terrible singularities, it is a tempered
distribution. Therefore we have
$$
(f, -\Delta \varphi) = (f, F^{-1}|\xi|^2F\varphi)
$$
when $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function (a function of rapid decay whose derivatives also decay rapidly).  Thus
$$
-\Delta f = F^{-1}|\xi|^2F f
$$
where the operators $\Delta$, $F$, and $F^{-1}$ are interpreted in the sense of
distributions. This is perhaps a vacuous statement, but the point is that, 
so long as $\Delta f$ is defined, you can write it in terms of the Fourier transform.